# Calculating E[XY] when X and Y have the same pdf?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Suppose we have some region $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for simplicity lets say its compact in the usual topology. Suppose that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are both uniformly distributed on $R$.

I seek $E[XY]$, which is defined [here](http://www2.econ.osaka-u.ac.jp/%7Etanizaki/class/2012/econome1/05.pdf) in the continuous case as $$\int_{R} x \cdot y \cdot p_{x,y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy $$ where I assume $p_{x,y}(x,y)$ is the joint PDF for $XY$. My issue is in finding such a joint distribution.

Given the scenario above, I would find the pdf of $X$, $Y$ to be $$p_x(x) = p_y(x) = \left[\int_{R} 1 \cdot d_{A} \right]^{-1} = c.$$

Can I use this to find $p_{xy}(x,y)$? I think I am misunderstanding some things.

The explicit problem that raised this quesion took the region $R$ to be the area bounded by $1-x^2$ and the positive axes. I found $c$ to be 1.5 but am not sure how to proceed.

Edit:
After receiving some comments that I am unable to answer I am going to post the specific problem that gave rise to my questions for clarity:

> “Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are
> uniformly distributed on the region bounded by the $x$ and $y$ axes and the curve $y = 1-x^2.$
>
> Calculate $E[XY]$”

In their solution they find $c=1.5$ and then perform the integration with integrand $xy1.5$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent? If not, then there's many possibilities for their joint PDF.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I was under the impression I should not assume independence since the question didn’t say it explicitly, but that’s part of why I can’t figure out what to do. I will edit my question add more details about the specific problem and maybe you will be able to tell from the context

Comment: Do you mean that $(X,Y)$ is uniforlmy distributed in $R$?

Comment: I am asking this because, to compute $E(XY)$, one needs $X$ and $Y$ to be real-valued, hence $X$ and $Y$ cannot be $\mathbb R^2$-valued... And you say that $R\subset\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Did I added the exact wording of the problem

Comment: ...Which is absurd. What is the source? Was there a translation to English involved?

Comment: If what they mean is that XY is uniform in $R$ then my question is solved

Comment: My guess is that **$(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on** $$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid x>0,y>0,y<1-x^2\}$$

Comment: It is. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: I’m embarrassed to say the source because I was originally going to pursue a PhD in algebra... this is from an actuarial study guide. It is not the first mis-wording I have found, but I am not an expert enough with probability to realize this one was a mistake.